# PHP - Connecting SQL Server

Tags: php, html, sql, web

Scenario:
I have 2 servers (win 2012 R2) 
1) SQL server 2017
2) WEB server (IIS 8.0)

They sit on the same subnet (NO Firewall play)

I am trying to connect to the sql server from my web site located on the other server, using "sqlsrv_connect()" function.

I can not connect the server, should I really need only the name of the server?

```
    <?php
        $server = "DatabaseServerName";
        $connectionInfo = ["DB" => "dbname", "username" => "Admin", "pwd" =>"Password123"] ;

$conn = $sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo) ;

If ($conn) {
echo "connection established';
} else {
echo" error";
} 
?>
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @Charis The quiestion is: Do I really should write only the name of the server?
because I am getting an error.

Comment: I guess you would get a syntax error ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you display the connection error using `sqlsrv_errors()`,but basically when your Sql Server is hosted on any other server and is not in the same network of your website host, you can't just write its name , you need to connect to Sql Server with ip address and it should allows Remote access connections. you need something like this :

```
    $server = "179.xx.x.xxx";
```

when your sql server and website are in the same network but different machines you can use `PDO` like this :

```
   $dbserver = new PDO("*dbtype*:dbname=*dbname*;host=*addressOfOtherMachine*", $user, $password);
```